# Is for each u,v in V loop linear on V?

Tags: graph, time-complexity, depth-first-search

Knowing that

```
for each u in V do // O(V)
     // ...
```

Does this loop:

```
for each u,v in V do // O(V) or O(V^2)?
     // ...
```

is linear on V or V^2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s O(V<sup>2</sup>). More generally, there are Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) pairs that can be made from a set of n items, and if you iterate over all them it’ll take quadratic time simply listing them out.